# Script to delete all log files except the latest 6 files in Linux

Tags: shell-script

Need a help to create a script on how to delete all log files and only keep the last generated 6 files (latest) in a directory. In my testing server /var/log/mqm file-system is getting full with in 2 to 3 days, So I need to remove the old log files using cron job.

This is what I have tried:
Here I thought that I will delete the files which are not created today. Unfortunately I'm not getting the expected result as I can see that everyday I'm getting more than 100 logs files. I actually required only the latest 6 files.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /var/log/mqm -name "*.LOG" -type f -mtime +1 > list_of_deleted_logs.out
find /var/log/mqm -name "*.LOG" -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Is this an exerciser? You seem to be re-inventing log rotation. If this is not a learning exercise, then use an existing log rotation tool. If it is an exercise then start by asking how you would do it manually. Once you can do it manually, then and only then consider automation.

Comment: There are also heaps of questions on this site about deleting the oldest N files, keeping only most recent N files, deleting files older than N days, etc.